# Issues installing SCIP for Python

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to install SCIP Optimization Suite for Python 2.7 (http://scip.zib.de/#download) on a windows machine. When I run the `setup_win.py`, I get an link error:

`fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'spx.lib'.`

Not, sure what I have to do to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might be missing the SCIP binaries, which are distributed separately from the source package in which the Python binding (with the setup_win.py) live. You should get that too.

Reading setup_win.py should give you some insight as to where the spx.lib is supposed to be.

Comment: I looked at the setup_win.py and I now know the folder these files are supposed to be in. however, nothing on their website that I can download has the name spx.lib. I have to add, I am fairly new to Python so maybe I am missing something else?